# How to get Windows language programmatically?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I need to install some version of one package depending on the SO language. How can I get it using a batch file? I'm using W7 professional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to identify the language codes that you care about. Here is one reference [MS Language Codes](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/languagecodes.php). Then you could get the code for the current windows install via wmic in your batch file:

```
wmic path win32_OperatingSystem get OSLanguage
```

From David's comment, to set the value, use the WMIC /value switch:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic path win32_OperatingSystem get OSLanguage /Value') do set Language=%%A
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works. I found also this other piece of code: `set Key="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International"
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query %Key%  ^| find /i "LocaleName"') do set Language=%%a`

Comment: How can I set that to a variable? @EBGreen

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita To set it to a variable use the `/Value` option and and a `for` loop parse: `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic path win32_OperatingSystem g
et OSLanguage /Value') do set Language=%%A`

Comment: in batch: delims= not delims==